# Переменные среды для работы с Qt5

Tags: установка, qt, c++

У меня возникла такая проблема:
При запуске Qt Command Prompt пишет:

```
Setting up environment for Qt usage...
```

При том, что системные переменные я настроил:
QTDIR и переменную PATH:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET QTDIR=E:\QT\5.4.1
SET QMAKESPEC=win32-g++
SET PATH=E:\QT\5.4.1\5.4\mingw491_32\bin;D:\mingw32\bin;
```

обычная настройка для меня

Answer (score 0):

Через QtCreator пробовали? В параметрах -> Сборка и запуск создайте профиль Qt для Qt5. Таким образом у меня никогда проблем не было. Заодно проверите, проблема у вас в установке путей или нет.